# How to select next element to the current

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My goal is to make an expand button show inner table which starts from `tr` tag. I have tried to do it using JQuery like this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.partTableContent').hide();
        $('.expandButton').click(function(){
            // .parent() selects the A tag, .next() selects the P tag
            $(this).parent().next().slideToggle(200);
        });
    });
</script>
```

The table I use

```
    <table class="partsTable" border="1px">
    <tr>
        <td class="sideForPartsTable" width="5%"><button class="expandButton">Expand button</button></td>
        <td class="sideForPartsTable">Title + sum1 + sum2</td>
        <td class="sideForPartsTable" width="5%">edit</td>
        <td class="sideForPartsTable" width="5%">remove</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <table class="partTableContent">
            <tr>
                <td> Test1 </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> Test2 </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </tr>
</table>
```

But it doesn't work the way it's expected. I understand that JQuery 'slideToggles' only next `td` tag inside this table. I also have tried something like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.partTableContent').hide();
    $('.expandButton').click(function(){
        // .parent() selects the A tag, .next() selects the P tag
        $(this).parent().nextAll('table:first').slideToggle(200);
    });
});
```

But it doesn't work too :c

Please consider that I have many "partsTable" and my goal is to make it work for all of them to expand ONLY corresponding sub-table.Thanks in advance

Comment: the inner table should be in `<td>` not in  `<tr>`;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Add td in the of table.
2. Use closest to get the parent tr of button then use next then find the table to target the table

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.partTableContent').hide();
  $('.expandButton').click(function() {
    // .parent() selects the A tag, .next() selects the P tag
    $(this).closest('tr').next(' tr').find('table').slideToggle(200);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="partsTable">

  <tr>

    <td class="sideForPartsTable" width="5%">
      <button class="expandButton">Expand button</button>
    </td>
    <td class="sideForPartsTable">Title + sum1 + sum2</td>
    <td class="sideForPartsTable" width="5%">edit</td>
    <td class="sideForPartsTable" width="5%">remove</td>

  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <table class="partTableContent">
        <tr>
          <td> Test1 </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td> Test2 </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! :3 Is there any way to make it appear not instantly, but smoothly?

Comment: according to the documents you can use `"slow"` like `.slideToggle( "slow" );` check [here](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/) for further info @J.Nick

Answer (score 0):

Use `closest()` to get the parent table and find the sub-table using `find()`, thereby removing the headache of traversing using `next()` or `tr`:

```
closest('table.partsTable').find('table.partTableContent')
```

---

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.partTableContent').hide();
  $('.expandButton').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('table.partsTable').find('table.partTableContent').slideToggle(1000);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="partsTable">

  <tr>

    <td class="sideForPartsTable" width="5%"><button class="expandButton">Expand button</button></td>
    <td class="sideForPartsTable">Title + sum1 + sum2</td>
    <td class="sideForPartsTable" width="5%">edit</td>
    <td class="sideForPartsTable" width="5%">remove</td>

  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <table class="partTableContent">
        <tr>
          <td> Test1 </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td> Test2 </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are hiding table element with the class name of '`partTableContent`'. Which is actually child of `<tr>` element you get with calling `$(this).parent().next()`

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
$('.partTableContent').hide(); 
$('.expandButton').click(function() {  
  $(this).parent().parent().next().children().children('.partTableContent').slideToggle(200); }); 
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="partsTable">

  <tr>

    <td class="sideForPartsTable" width="5%">
      <button class="expandButton">Expand button</button>
    </td>
    <td class="sideForPartsTable">Title + sum1 + sum2</td>
    <td class="sideForPartsTable" width="5%">edit</td>
    <td class="sideForPartsTable" width="5%">remove</td>

  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <table class="partTableContent">
        <tr>
          <td> Test1 </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td> Test2 </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```